# Получить из ФИО Фамилию и инициалы имени и отчества

Tags: oracle

Есть таблица `man` с полем `text`. Поле содержит ФИО полностью. Как можно получить фамилию и инициалы имени и отчества?

Например вместо Иванов Сергей Михайлович получить Иванов С.М.

Comment: 1. а если у человека нет отчества? 2. а если фио звучит как «[Полад Муртуза оглы Мамедов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8B,_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4)»? // то, что вы хотите — это, для 100%-ного «попадания», практически нереализуемо. для получения более однозначной картины надо хранить отдельно фамилию, имя и отчество. и то, это не поможет в случае состаных имён, всяких родовых обозначений и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Таких имен нет. Справочник небольшой и статичный

Comment: так позаменяйте вручную: `$ echo 'Иванов Сергей Михайлович' | sed 's/ /  /;s/ \([^ ]\)[^ ]*/\1./g'`

Comment: Это что? В oracle можно так делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация в Oracle

```
with man as (
select 'Иванов Петр Васильевич' as text from dual union all
select 'Борисов Богдан Егорович' as text from dual union all
select 'Жуков Никита Тимофеевич' as text from dual)

select man.text,
regexp_replace(man.text, ' (.*)',' ',2,1) || 
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(man.text, ' (.*)|^[^ ]* '),'.*','.',2,1)||
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(man.text, '(.*) '),'.*','.',2,1) INITIALS
from man;
--------------------------------------------------------------------
TEXT                            INITIALS
Иванов Петр Васильевич          Иванов П.В.
Борисов Богдан Егорович         Борисов Б.Е.
Жуков Никита Тимофеевич         Жуков Н.Т.
```

- пример на фидле
  [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3cc8ff22429c354bf985a0be99410f8b)